# Resize to fit image in div, and center horizontally and vertically

Tags: css, image, center

I have an image in a div. I would like the image to resize to fit the div, and be horizontally and vertically centered. I would like a solution that works in ie >= 8.

Answer (score 49):

This is one way to do it:

Fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/4Mvan/1/

**HTML:**

```
<div class='container'>
    <a href='#'>
    <img class='resize_fit_center'
      src='http://i.imgur.com/H9lpVkZ.jpg' />
    </a>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
.resize_fit_center {
    max-width:100%;
    max-height:100%;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

Comment: Why the `<a>` around the image? Is there any reason other than making the image a link? (Which wasn't part of the question.)

Comment: @Jens You can just skip the `<a>` and `</a>` and it will still work. (It is indeed not part of the question, it is just to show that you can make your image a link and it won't break)

Comment: You have asked the question and then instantly answered to it... WHY?

Comment: @Saty I was about to answer another question about centring an image in a div, but because my requirements are a bit different (resize to git + center horizontal + center vertical), I decided that it was worth creating a new question before posting my answer. [Answering your own questions is encouraged](http://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer).

Comment: Unfortunately, this solution does not scale up the image: http://jsfiddle.net/4Mvan/438/

Comment: my container has a dynamic width (it's actually the whole window), so can't set a fixed `line-height`, and `100%` doesn't work. i'm using javascript to set it but let me know if there is a better (css) way ;-)

Answer (score 33):

Only tested in Chrome 44.

Example: http://codepen.io/hugovk/pen/OVqBoq

HTML:

```
<div>
<img src="http://lorempixel.com/1600/900/">
</div>
```

CSS:

```
<style type="text/css">
img {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
    max-width: 100%;
    max-height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Comment: Many thanks, it works. One addition is that you should set style `position: relative` for div.

Comment: i checked the solution from @hugo and ended up with a similar approach, what worked perfectly for my needs, and also in IE.
My solution: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RLPVaq

Comment: Yeah, the translate on x- and y-axis are crusial. If your image is too large you can always change the max-values.

Comment: Still good 7 years later. Also used `position: relative`. Thanks.

Answer (score 10):

**NOT SUPPORTED BY IE**

More info here: [Can I Use?](https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit)

```css
.container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
}

.container img {
  object-fit: cover;
  width: 100%;
  min-height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='container'>
    <img src='http://i.imgur.com/H9lpVkZ.jpg' />
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

SOLUTION

```
<style>
.container {
    margin: 10px;
    width: 115px;
    height: 115px;
    line-height: 115px;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid red;
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/H9lpVkZ.jpg");
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: contain;

}

</style>

<div class='container'>
</div>

<div class='container' style='width:50px;height:100px;line-height:100px'>
</div>

<div class='container' style='width:140px;height:70px;line-height:70px'>
</div>
```